# GLSL shader programming #version header error: unrecognized preprocessing directive

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I just started GLSL shader programing, but however I get 
`unrecognized preprocessing directive` 
whenever I put `#version` directive at the preprocessor directives header stack, though I included all opengl related headers and files within my source file,

**Shader:**

```
#version 400
in vec3 Color; 
out vec4 FragColor; 
void main() 
{ 
    FragColor = vec4(Color, 1.0); 
}
```

**how can I fix this issue?**

Comment: Did you specify which version you're using?  Such as `#version 150`

Comment: Post your source code (both glsl and the main application), opengl version and operating system.

Comment: As @JoakimGebart said, we can't help without more informations. Did you check your OpenGL version running?

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer for sure i specified the version but yet gives the same error!!!

Comment: @JoakimGebart well iam stuck at the point where the preprocessor directives are being declared (beginning of coding) my problem is that why #version is not considered as a directive in the first place !!! all of the other directives get highlighted except #version

Comment: @FelixK. as i mentioned iam stuck at the very beginning of the program so there is not much of a hard code program in hand the #version should be accepted as a directive in the first place!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `#version` directive must occur in a shader before anything else, except for comments and white space.

Even preprocessor directives are illegal ( NVIDIA accepts it but AMD does not! ).
If this doesn't help, give us some more information. E.g. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)`.

Refering to your comments you missunderstand how a shader is compiled. A shader cannot be compiled by a C++ compiler. Put your shader into a text file and load it at runtime, then call the compilation methods of OpenGL.

Comment: this also gave me the same error!! is there any specific file regarding shader programs?? forexample i wrote mine in a .cpp file, and if the directive should come before any other directives how does the compiler identifies this as a valid preprocessor directive (since it is GLSL specific directive)

Comment: @user1788024 Please not so many `!!!`'s. Please post your shader, even if you say its simple. Than we can sure that there is no other issue.

Comment: '#version 400
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 FragColor;
void main() {
FragColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}'

Comment: @user1788024 How did you wrote your shader into a cpp file?

Comment: i made a new project file, and added a .cpp file which is different from the original program's .cpp file but in the  same source folder, i did so in order to eliminate future linking errors.

Comment: @user1788024 As a string? Because normaly you write your shader into a text file not a cpp file and load the text file at runtime.

Comment: no actually i wrote it so that the compiler would treat it as an individual program, i didn't know that it should be written as a string, my references didn't mentioned this.

Comment: @user1788024 A shader cannot be compiled by a C++ compiler by default. Shaders must be compiled by OpenGL on request. I gonna add it to my answer.

Comment: so that is the point, well now things make sense thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The `#version` pre-processor command is run at the c++ compile time, `glsl` is only text based and shouldn't be compiled. If you `#include "file"` in a header or `.cpp` in the program it will trigger the compile and error. Therefore don't `#include` glsl files into you application.